# OS X Snow Leopard, change file permissions on copy

Tags: mac-osx, file-permissions

I work with OS X, Snow Leopard and need to allow users to make copies of files (templates) located in a read-only repository for subsequent editing.

The repository is located on a separate physical drive mounted to the OS X boot volume.

As this is a shared computer in a school environment, all users access the machine via a single login ("user_local").

Whether using POSIX permissions or ACLs, the use case requires the file permissions to change from "read" to "read write" as they get copied to the "user_local" home directory.

Googling around has not yielded anything that would indicate that this is possible via the Snow Leopard permission system.

Question 1:
Is this in fact possible via the permission system?
If so, how?

Question 2:
If not possible, how would one go about solving this problem?
I imagine this to be a fairly common use case so there must be a workable solution for it out there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I would probably do if presented this is to write a little bash script. You can use the `cp` command to copy the file. [cp link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cp.1.html) The chmod command will allow you to change the permissions. [chmod link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/chmod.1.html) You should be able to set up a cron job to run every night or whenever you needed. Make sure when running the script you have fallen into `sudo -s` or `sudo` in front of every command. There is a way to lock the file on ubuntu so you aren't required to enter `sudo` or `sudo -s` but I can't think about it off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the original templates read/write but **not** writeable by the local_user, then both Finder drag copy and `cp` will preserve the original file permissions, but not owner.

So if the original template files have permissions like:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel  ... rw-file
-r--r--r--   1 root  wheel  ... ro-file
```

When some **unprivileged** local_user copies those file into their own dir they will become:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 local_user  staff  ... Documents/rw-file
-r--r--r--  1 local_user  staff  ... Documents/ro-file
```

See that the 'rw-' attributes of root-owned file "rw-file" were preserved even though the owner changed in the new copies.

Comment: Works as advertised. So simple too, not sure what I did wrong in the first place. In any case, thanks for taking the time to answer.